# With Ivy/Counsel, why are some foreground colors in `M-x` a different color than others?

Tags: faces, minibuffer, ivy, counsel, m-x

Please see the picture below. Why are some things colored orange? I can't figure out what Face is causing that. This is using Ivy/Counsel.

[image]

Comment: Is it the face `counsel-active-mode`?

Comment: Never used `ivy/counsel` before, so I installed them and enabled `ivy-mode`. `M-x` then gives me a monochromatic list (altough I only get the LH column: probably missing an option). So probably `ivy/counsel` have something to do with it, but maybe they are not the whole story?

Comment: Indeed, `counsel-active-mode` was the culprit. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You originally had tag `minibuffer`. Where is what you see in the screenshot? Is it in a buffer where you can place the cursor? If so, put the cursor on one of those lines and use `C-u C-x =`. The `*Help*` buffer will then tell you which faces are used at that buffer position (near the bottom of `*Help*`).

If you can't put your cursor on any of that text then you can try using `M-x list-faces-display` and seeing if you can match what you see against the display of faces. E.g., look for face names that start with whatever prefix Ivy/Counsel uses generally.

Otherwise, you can check the source code of the library responsible for this, e.g. Ivy or Counsel. Look for `defface` (e.g. use `M-x grep`).

As for *why* different faces are used, look at the doc strings of the two faces, using `M-x describe-face`. That should tell you something about the specific purpose of each face.

Comment: The screenshot is of the minibuffer. When I put my cursor over one of the orange options, it highlights it so the face changes, so `C-u C-x =` wasn't helpful there. Prior to posting this question I did look at `M-x list-faces-display` for Ivy, but didn't think to do so for Counsel. There is a Face called `Counsel-active-mode` which seems to be causing the behavior I've asked about as noted in one of the comments to my question. Changing it fixes the issue.

Comment: On another note, I noticed you deleted the `minibuffer` tag. Since this is happening in the minibuffer I thought it was appropriate. Can you help me understand why that tag is not appropriate here?

Comment: Glad you found the face and solved your problem. I removed tag `minibuffer` because I wasn't sure (still am not) that that displayed text is actually in the minibuffer. @Shynur reinstated the tag, so probably it is appropriate. I'm still guessing (blindly) that that displayed text may be, e.g., from an *overlay* on the minibuffer.